# DJANGO - How to display a text form field next to checked checkboxes

Tags: python, django

I am creating an application that allows you to add predefined services to an invoice. When creating a new invoice, you can select services using checkboxes. I would like to add the text field to specify the quantity after selecting the checkbox. So you check the checkbox and text field appears next to it where you can enter the quantity. I would like to store this data in the database after creating a new invoice. I am not sure how can I achieve this. Do I need JS or only Django is enough?

UPDATE 7.06.2020
models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
    nazwa = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cena = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.nazwa} - cena: {self.cena}zł'

class ServiceItem(models.Model):
    usluga = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ilosc = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.usluga.nazwa} - cena: {self.usluga.cena}zł'

class Invoice(models.Model):
    forma_platnosci_wybor = [
        ('przelew', 'przelew'),
        ('gotowka', 'gotówka')
    ]

    numer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    firma = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    forma_platnosci = models.CharField(verbose_name='forma płatności', max_length=75, choices=forma_platnosci_wybor)
    data_badania = models.DateField()
    data_wystawienia_faktury = models.DateTimeField()

    rabat = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='rabat [%]', blank=True, null=True)
    uslugi = models.ManyToManyField(ServiceItem, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.numer
```

forms.py

```
class NewInvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['numer', 'data_wystawienia_faktury']
        widgets = {
            'usluga' : forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            'data_badania' : DateInput(),
        }
```

template form

```
<legend class="col-12">Tworzenie nowej faktury</legend>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                {{ form.firma | as_crispy_field}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                {{ form.forma_platnosci | as_crispy_field}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                {{ form.data_badania | as_crispy_field}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                {{ form.rabat | as_crispy_field}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                {{ form.uslugi | as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"><i class="far fa-edit"></i> Zatwierdź fakturę</button>
    </form>
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTCRW.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the check box to be clicked before the form will be able to appear right? If that's the case js idea Will have to be put in place

Answer (score 0):

You will need to render hidden text field and make it visible with JS, for example using onclick event on the checkbox. If this is a single ocurance on the form it might be simple, if it is multiple ocurances of dynamically generated checkboxes and text field it might be a little bit more difficult - but doable.

Comment: Ok but how can I store this additional data in the DB?

Comment: So, the JS will handle only the part of activating field in the form, nothing more. If you wish to store this fields than you will need additional modal that has relations to both your models where you can store those additional fields. I would personally make inline frameset where user can add additional rows to invoice from pull-down menu with services or maybe from select2 field. Maybe that is the way to go. It really depends how many services do you expect to have in the end.

Comment: So I am expecting to have no more than 5 services on the invoice but I would like to choose them using multiple checkboxes. I created another model: ServiceItem (you will find updated code in my first msg). Is any way to show in my template ilosc(quantity) integer field?

Comment: I tried with formset. It's like: 

ServiceFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Service, ServiceItem, fields=('ilosc',))

But how can I display one field for one checkbox position? Currently I have something like on picture in the first post.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any pictures. Having the option to dynamically add services is much more scalable than to have everything in code. When you create formset every row becomes a form of its own, so you can create additional form and add it while you create inlineformset_factory ans you can control which field are visible and which are hidden as in any form. Plus, you can render everything in table so that you can then opt to add new services.

Comment: Could You provide some example code with adding services dynamically? I tried to use formset with queryset = ServiceItem.objects.all() because I thought I will get quantity field for every created ServiceItem object but it doesn't worked like that.

Comment: When you render your master form + formset (that includes a number of detailed forms) you get a fixed number of lines to enter. It can be controlled by using extra parameter when constructing inline_formset. If you wish to be able to dynamically add more lines you will need to do by yorself with JS or with tools like django-dynamic-formset - which I would recommend.

Comment: I personally use select2 to render fields in detailed forms, but if you have just  like 5 services maybe select2 is overhead. If you wish to try select2 in formset, here is a good starting point: https://github.com/anneFly/django-dynamic-formset-select2-poc

Comment: Ok Thank You I will definitely check links you have provided. But before that I would like to make sure that I understand it properly. This is what I want to do: 
1. On the invoice creation form I would like to display all services available in db as checkboxes
2. Near every service I would like to have a text field to enter quantity
3. Backend will check which services are marked and takes the quantity to create the invoice
Do I really need addidtional libs to make that or django built-in libs will be enough?